# Ubuntu bash on windows 10 stopped working

Tags: windows-10, bash

After one of updates my windows stopped supporting  ubuntu bash. Error looks like this:

```
Приложение, которое вы пытаетесь запустить, не поддерживается в этой версии Windows.


Current directory:
C:\Users\%USERNAME%

Command to be executed:
"C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe"


ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=xFFFFFFFF(4294967295).
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

Translation is something like `The application that you are trying to run is not supported in this version of Windows.`

The following commands and reinstallation linux subsystem didn't help

```
lxrun /uninstall /full 
lxrun /install
```

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you running Windows 10 LTSB?

Here is said that LTSB won't support WSL until stable release.
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1281

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Unfortunately, your answer does not meet the good answer standards for which we strive. It is probably better suited as a comment. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174).

Comment: Yea, seems so. So the only way to have bash on windows is to have windows 10 pro on pc, i guess. Its time to reinstall windows... Again